Creating QuadElements from a set of points
I am new in Mathematica.
Is it possible to create QuadElements from a set of points?
In this link there is an explanation for creating triangleElement.
Suppose I have only coordinates of my points as follows
dd = {{0.25, 0.25}, {0.5, 0.25}, {0.75, 0.25}, {0.25, 0.5}, {0.5, 
    0.5}, {0.75, 0.5}, {0.25, 0.75}, {0.5, 0.75}, {0.75, 0.75}, {0.25,
     1}, {0.5, 1}, {0.75, 1}, {0.25, 1.25}, {0.5, 1.25}, {0.75, 
    1.25}, {0.25, 1.5}, {0.5, 1.5}, {0.75, 1.5}, {0.25, 1.75}, {0.5, 
    1.75}, {0.75, 1.75}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 0.25}, {1, 0.25}, {0, 
    0.5}, {1, 0.5}, {0, 0.75}, {1, 0.75}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 
    1.25}, {1, 1.25}, {0, 1.5}, {1, 1.5}, {0, 1.75}, {1, 1.75}, {0, 
    2}, {1, 2}, {0.25, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.75, 0}, {0.25, 2}, {0.5, 
    2}, {0.75, 2}};

I want to create quadElements from this set.
Thank you for your help.

Can you be more specific? What are QuadElements?

I mean quadrilateral mesh. See for example here

I want to understand QuadElements is always well-defined or not. Suppose you have just five points --- the vertices of a regular pentagon. Then, what is the expected answer?

The command ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 2}], MaxCellMeasure -> 1/16] will create a mesh of QuadElements through those particular points.

ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]

Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
triMesh = ToElementMesh[dd];
mesh = ToQuadMesh[triMesh];
mesh["Wireframe"]



Thank you very much.
